# Creating a list of arrays

Tags: java, python

I am having a  data in the form of `ids` and `value` , where the value of ids are not continuous , i want to store the data in arraylist.

For Java:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] Data = new ArrayList[1000000];
for(int i=0;i<Data.length;i++) Data[i] = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int id_index = in.nextInt();
    int value = in.nextInt();
    Data[id_index].add(value);
}
```

How to implement the same functionality in Python ?

Comment: So you read from stdin?

Comment: Some remarks on your code: variable names in java should always start with a lowercase letter (`Data -> data`). Furhtermore, long variable names should be written in [camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case#In_word_combinations) (`id_index -> idIndex`). As to your code: you mentioned that the `id`s are not-continuous. Maybe a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` or a `Map<Integer, Integer[]>` could be more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

A list of lists will do fine, which can be created as so:

```
data = [[] for i in range(1000000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Alex Hall's answer stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45264706/4216641), you can use a list of lists as the following:

```
data = [[] for i in range(1000000)]
```

I just want to add the second part of your code:

```
for _ in range(n):
    id_index, value = raw_input().split()
    data[int(id_index)].append(int(value))
```

If you are using python 3.x then change `raw_input()` to `input()`

Comment: You're assuming a particular input format which can't be inferred from the question. At least clarify what that input format looks like for someone who may have trouble understanding the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think different way.
python is a dynamic type language. dose not need to define variables like java.

just append every things u like, by every size you want!

```
>>> x=[]
>>> x.append([12])
>>> x
[[12]]
>>> x.append([15,16,17])
>>> x
[[12], [15, 16, 17]]
```